# Error performing LD clumping on SNP data using R TwoSampleMR

Tags: reference, missing-data, panel-data, rscript, unused-functions

I am to perform LD clumping on SNP data  using R TwoSampleMR  and I am getting the following error message:

> Exp_Out_Harmonized_Clumped < -clump_data(harmonized,clump_kb = 10000,clump_r2 = 0.1,clump_p1 = 1,clump_p2 = 1,pop = "AFR")
> Error in clump_data(harmonized, clump_kb = 10000, clump_r2 = 0.1, clump_p1 = 1,  : unused argument (pop = "AFR").

Perform clumping and my target population is African (pop=AFR)